# Reading files using system calls and printing lines

Tags: c, printf, output, system-calls

This program reads a text file "hello.txt" and looks for the occurrence of the string w in it and prints the number of the line and the whole line. It also prints how many times the string w has occurred in the file. The program compiles with no errors, here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int fd;
    char c;
    char str[152];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int bytesread;
    int flag = 1;
    int found = 0;
    int line = 1;
    int foundflag = 1;

    char w[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    int len = strlen(w);

    if ((fd = open("hello.txt", O_RDONLY, 0)) != -1) { //if 1

        bytesread = read(fd, &c, 1);
        str[j] = c;
        j++;

        if (bytesread != -1) { //if 2

            while (bytesread != 0) { //while

                if (c == '\n')
                    line++;

                if (c == w[i]) { //if 3
                    i++;
                    flag = 0;
                } else if (flag == 0 || i == len) //end of f3
                { // else 3
                    i = 0;
                    flag = 1;
                }// end of else 3
                else if (flag == 1) {
                    while (read(fd, &c, 1)) {
                        str[j] = c;
                        j++;
                        if (c == ' ')
                            break;
                        if (c == '\n') {
                            line++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                bytesread = read(fd, &c, 1);
                str[j] = c;
                j++;

                if ((c == ' ' || c == '\n') && flag == 0 && i == len) {
                    found++;
                    foundflag = 0;
                    printf("w was found in line %d.\n", line);
                }

                if ((c == '\n')&&(foundflag == 0)) {

                    for (j = 0; str[j] != '\n'; j += 5) {
                        printf("%c", str[j]);

                        if (str[j + 1] != '\n')
                            printf("%c", str[j + 1]);
                        else {
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (str[j + 2] != '\n')
                            printf("%c", str[j + 2]);
                        else {
                            j += 2;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (str[j + 3] != '\n')
                            printf("%c", str[j + 3]);
                        else {
                            j += 3;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (str[j + 4] != '\n')
                            printf("%c", str[j + 4]);
                        else {
                            j += 4;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    for (; str[j] != '\n'; j++)
                        printf("%c", str[j]);

                    printf("\n");
                    j = 0;

                } else if (c == '\n')
                    foundflag = 1;

            } //end of while
            printf("w has occured %d times.\n", found);

        } else //end of if 2
            printf("couldn't read file.\n");

    } else //end of if 1
        printf("Couldn't open file for read.\n");

    close(fd);
} //end of main
```

This is the output in the terminal:

```
w was found in line 1.
hello
w was found in line 2.
w was found in line 6.
hello world
hellooooo
w has occured 3 times.
```

and here is the content of "hello.txt":

```
hello
hello world
hallo
I'm here
we're here
hello
hellooooo
```

the number of lines printed in the output are 1,2 & 6, but this is what the output should look like:

```
w was found in line 1.
hello
w was found in line 2.
hello world
w was found in line 6.
hello
w has occured 3 times.
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow down the code to just the parts you have problem with. Or better yet, please make a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't use `strncmp` to test for the occurrence of `w`?

Comment: But in the parts I *did* read I see some *undefined behavior* almost immediately. You treat the array `w` as a string, but you seem to forget that strings in C are *terminated*, and the array `w` does not have this terminator, so when you e.g. call `strlen` it will go out of bounds and you will have UB.

Comment: Use `char w[]="Hello";` instead of `char w[]={'h','e','l','l','o'};`. This is more readable and (most important in your case), it adds a zero terminator. See comments before.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is your question "How do you debug C code?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I suggest you read some C material. You code suggests you don't know much about the language yet.
2. I won't change your code, since that'd be hard.
3. I'll post the relevant parts of my code and explain the bits.

---

So, the code bits:

```
const char fname[] = "hello.txt";
const char w[] = "hello";

(...)    

while (read(fd, &buffer[i], 1) == 1) {
    /* end of line */
    if (buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == 0x0) {
        buffer[i] = 0;
        if (!strncmp(buffer, w, strlen(w))) {
            printf("w was found in line %d\n", line);
            puts(buffer);
            n++;
        }
        line++;
        i = 0;
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

---

### Explanation

1. **`while (read(fd, &buffer[i], 1) == 1)`**: 
   This will read one character from your `fd` (which was returned by an earlier `open` call) and store that at buffer[i]. The relevant thing to note here is that before this you should have declared `int i = 0` and make sure `buffer` is either a defined array or a `malloc`ed memory region. This `while` will go on until the amount of bytes read is different than 1 (which was what we asked for).
2. **`if (buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == 0x0)`**: This `if` detects an end of line. Pretty straight-forward.
3. **`buffer[i] = 0;`** and **`if (!strncmp(buffer, w, strlen(w)))`**: `buffer[i] = 0` will set the last character of the current buffer to zero. What this does is it gets rid of the last `\n` we read, so we can print it nicely with `puts`. The bit I suggested in the comments is the use of [strncmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncmp.3.html). This function is just like `strcmp`, but it will only compare *at most* a defined number of bytes. So, with this function, you can effectively determine if a string starts with the substring you're looking for. If this string is found, we print the line in which it is, print the buffer itself and increment `n`, which is our counter on how many times `w` was found. You should have declared `int n = 0;` in the beginning of the code...
4. **`line++; i = 0; continue;`** :This is inside the end-of-line detection `if`. So, what this does is it increments our line counter, sets `i` to zero - this is important, because at a new line we're gonna read a new buffer, and that buffer index must start at 0. And `continue` forces a loop repetition without executing the rest of the code.
5. Finally, the rest of the `while` scope is defined as **`i++`**. As our while loop executes at every character, the buffer index must get incremented after every character read.

---

The file I tested with is the one you provided. The output I got was:

```
w was found in line 1
hello
w was found in line 2
hello world
w was found in line 6
hello
w was found 3 times
```

Comment: What do you mean by buffer[i] = 0x0?

Comment: @Raghad Inside the first `if` _condition_, it checks if the read character was a null character. Inside the `if` _scope_ it sets the last character to a null terminated byte - that way, we effectively remove the `\n` that was read into `buffer[i]`.

Comment: How do I know if the word I'm looking for is in the middle or the end of the buffer?

Comment: @Raghad You'll have to parse the line character by character doing `strncmp` in each part to find. This version only looks for matches in the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Raghad Instead of testing for the ocurrency of words only after newlines, keep a buffer of what you have already read, then compare against that buffer.

Comment: You mean that I create another buffer to store the word I've read and compare it to the other buffer?

Comment: @Raghad If you want to search within the line, you must hold at least the amount of bytes being compared. I suggest you read the line and then use [strstr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) for simplicity.

Comment: I changed the while-loop condition to rio_readn(fd, &buffer, 152) to read line by line. and used strstr in if-statement. if((chr=strstr(buffer,w))!=NULL){ printf("w was found in line %d\n", line); puts(buffer); found++;} but it prints the whole file content not just the first line.

Comment: @Raghad `buffer` is gonna have 152 bytes at max. So that probably means your file is 152 bytes. To strip things line by line you'll need to detect `\n` characters. Also, I have no idea what `rio_readn` does, but I'm guessing it reads the whole file, not line by line.

Comment: I changed again to read(fd,&buffer,152) to read line by line. but it still reads several lines cus the line might be less than 152. how do I stop it till the \n? And I also used   if((chr=strstr(buffer,w))!=NULL){ printf("w was found in line %d\n", line); puts(buffer); found++;}

Comment: @Raghad If you want to read line by line, use [fgets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html). `read` will read `count` bytes, it doesn't care what character it is.

Comment: @Raghad Note that to use `fgets` you'll need a file descriptor returned by `fopen`. You can't use the `fd` returned by an `open` call.

Comment: I can't use fgets and fopen. I have to use systemcalls

Comment: @Raghad Right, I forgot about that. So, have a buffer called `line` where you store your information. When you find a `\n` character you know you just finished reading the line, then you use `strstr` on that buffer.

Comment: I have another question, why do I get a segmentation fault every time before the code terminates?

Comment: @Raghad Maybe you're trying to free some memory you shouldn't. Or writing somewhere you can't... Hard to say without looking at code. Ah, Please upvote my answer if I helped. ;)

Comment: @Raghad Sure, you can use CodePad, PasteBin, Ideone, Git, or something like that...

Comment: Yep. thanks. but I'm having a problem reading a huge file (over 5 GB). It says that it can't allocate memory and the program is too slow

Comment: @Raghad Don't allocate 5GB to load a file, instead, read it in _chunks_. For instance, make your own "fgets", say, "file_gets", that will read into a buffer until a newline is found. Have that buffer be one chunk large, for instance, 4096 bytes (I don't think your file has a line with more than 4096 bytes, does it?). Then you can abstract away the `read` system call and use your own function that reads lines. Again, don't try to allocate 5GB of memory to load and parse a file.

Comment: I know that I have to get the size of the file and then decrement the buffer size from the file size each time. so I can reach the end of the file